# regex (multiline) - match only if all lines do not contain $

Tags: regex, multiline

I need help with a regex.
I have a text like this which contains several lines:

```
Message=A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SERVER1$
    Account Domain:     EXAMPLE.ORG
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
    Account Name:       user1
    Account Domain:     EXAMPLE.ORG
    Logon GUID:     {15CEA50D-0E2C-2FFC-6FDF-46CDFC48AE34}

Target Server:
    Target Server Name: localhost
    Additional Information: localhost

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x38e0
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe

Network Information:
    Network Address:    10.9.8.7
    Port:           0
```

I need a regexp that will match the whole message, if ALL strings with

```
 Account Name:
```

lines are followed by a text with '$'

In this example there are two lines with `"Account Name:"` - one has `'$'` in it, second doesn't so shouldn't be matched. If there are one or more lines with `"Account Name:"`, but all of them contain `'$'` then match.

I've tried different ones like this:

```
(?s)Account Name:\s+(?!(\$))\n.*
```

but didn't manage to achieve my goal.

Comment: Try [`/\A(?!.*^\h*Account Name:[^$\n\r]*$).*\z/sm`](https://regex101.com/r/uE2kO0/1) for PCRE.

Comment: OP, could you verify that the title accurately describes the problem? In my interpretation, it describes something different than the content (it should probably go along the lines of "(...) match only if all lines containing a certain string contain $").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(?s)^(?!.*\bAccount Name:[^$\n]*(?:\n|$)).*
```

This pattern uses a negative lookahead to make sure there is no Account Name with no $-character, then just matches the entire text.

Comment: Thank you! It's working.
The only isssue is that newline character here [^$\n] is ignored for some reason, regex matches $ in any part of string with Account Name.